# Tell datagridview to ignore 'NULL' cells

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, null

I've got a piece of code that reads integers and date values from a `datagridview`. Some of the `k` values have null entries in and i'm trying to get the app to ignore those cells but I'm not having any luck. The error pops up on the line
`j = datediff...`.

I've tried using an if statement to ignore the values if they are null but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    For k = 3 To 7 Step 2

        Dim j As Integer

        j = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k - 2).Value, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k).Value)

        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k + 3).Value = 0 Then

            If j > 7 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k + 1).Value = 3
            Else
            End If

        Else
        End If

    Next k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if cell value is null:

```
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k + 1).Value Is Nothing Then
' your code
End If
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! will be accepting this as answer